# how to use zone() on Meteor.users.find({})

Tags: meteor, angular2-meteor

Now in angular2-meteor we started using MongoObservable.Collection in place of Mongo.Cursor and zone() method which helps in collection changes into our view using our Component's Zone and | async in html template. here is link of [latest tutorial](https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/3-way-data-binding)

Now i am trying to use this zone() method on my Meteor.users.find({}) method to automatically display all the users in my app when any new user created successfully.

**Code on my server side**

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function() {
    if (Roles.userIsInRole(this.userId, 'admin')) {
        return Meteor.users.find();
    } else {
        const selector = {
            '_id': this.userId
        };
        return Meteor.users.find(selector);
    }
});
```

and on client side i have used

```
userlist: Observable<any[]>;
userSData: Subscription;
     ngOnInit() {
            this.usersData = MeteorObservable.subscribe('userData').subscribe(() => {
                this.userlist=Meteor.users.find({}).fetch();
            });
```

html code is

```
   <li class="list-item" *ngFor="let user of userlist">
```

when i apply .zone() to this `this.userlist = Meteor.users.find({}).zone();`
i get this error.

```
TypeError: meteor_1.Meteor.users.find(...).zone is not a function
```

if i don't use zone() and | async then i get all the user list but if i delete any user or create any new user my list is not automatically updating i have to refresh. For automatic rendering new content we have to use zone and async but its not working with Meteor.users.find().

Comment: I am new to Meteor and Angular and I am trying to just list the users. However, I am getting an error on this.userlist=Meteor.users.find({}).fetch();, that it cannot be assigned. Is it working for you properly?

Comment: your collection declaration should be like this.    `export const Users = MongoObservable.fromExisting(Meteor.users);`  then you can access it like this `this.usersData = MeteorObservable.subscribe('userData').subscribe(() => { 
                 this.userlist=Users.find({}).zone();      
        });`

Comment: Thanks! This works!

Comment: @AmitSuhag's answer is fully correct and cleaner than Jesper's solution, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the view doesn't update ... try to use NgZone (import it from @angular/core) and use it in your subscription, like this:

```
constructor(private ngZone: NgZone) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.clientsSub = MeteorObservable.subscribe('myClients').subscribe(() => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.clients = Clients.find({}, {sort: {name: 1}});
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as correct, for people who have the same problem in the future! :)

Comment: It looks like this solution causes some extra work for the client.
In practice it should not be noticeable when the client has access to only a small record set.
Why extra work? Because what this code appears to say is: "whenever the server makes us aware of a change in a record set, just get a new cursor and use that to mirror the collection locally". But when getting a new cursor, the subscriber has no choice but resync the whole set. The price of such an operation is proportional to the size of record set.